# Firebase Crashlytics | Swift Package Manager (SPM) Run Script?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I want to add `Crashlytics` to my app using the Swift package manager.

Now, since the usual way to install `Firebase` is through `CocoaPods`, the  [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=ios#swift) on how to set up `Crashlytics` properly is also adjusted for `CocoaPods`.

In other words - the run script we should copy from the tutorial is not compatible with SPM, as you can see here:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run
```

So how can I find the file location of `Crashlytics` using SPM to get the correct run script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Turns out its inside the `DerivedData` folder:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YOURAPP-.../SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run
```

For your convenience, you can use a build variable to generalize the folder path:

```
${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run
```

Finally, your run script should look something like that:

[image]

Comment: It seems to now be `"${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/Crashlytics/run"`

Comment: ${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run worked for me, Xcode 12.5. OMG THANK YOU

Comment: Now it's "${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"

Answer (score 5):

And another quite important thing if a non-default name for the firebase configuration file is used.
This flag is needed to denote it:

```
-gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/PATH-TO-CONFIG/GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist
```

Thus final script should look like

```
${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/PATH-TO-CONFIG/GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist
```

Where PATH-TO-CONFIG is the path to the firebase configuration file in the project.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, but I had to change Project Settings.

`"${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions. I'm unable to make this work. I get a crash and the following error message:

/Users/[path-to-my-project]/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I don't understand why it tries to find the crashlytics script in my Xcode project folder and not in the derived data folder at runtime.

Comment: I got the solution. in Xcode Preferences go to: Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Advanced and select the first option "Unique". Firebase expects the build folder to be located there.